# Inspecting ui elements in react native apps

Tags: react-native

Is there a way I can inspect ui elements in my app, the same way I can inspect ui elements in Websites. I want to see for each element how much space it occupies, margins and etc... the same way it works with DevTools in chrome.

Comment: https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging#docsNav show inspector will show in the mobile.

Comment: You can use flipper -> https://fbflipper.com/